# Deadlock prevention :Mutual Exclusion

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, deadlock

Deadlock prevention say :

> All **four** of the conditions are **necessary** for deadlock to occur, it follows that deadlock might be prevented by denying any one of the conditions.

### Conditions

1. **Mutual Exclusion**
2. **Hold and Wait**
3. **No Premption**
4. **Circular Wait**

Now

Let us deny first one

> 1. **Mutual Exclusion**

There are many examples to prove that **Mutual Exclusion** may lead to deadlock like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215717/if-mutual-exclusion-is-guaranteed-say-with-semaphores-is-a-program-deadlock-fr?rq=1) .

Now let us prevent this **Mutual Exclusion** .But the problem is that

> The mutual exclusion condition must hold for non-sharable resources. That is, several processes cannot simultaneously share a single resource. This condition is difficult to eliminate because some resources, such as the tape drive and printer, are inherently non-shareable.check [this](http://www.personal.kent.edu/%7Ermuhamma/OpSystems/Myos/deadlockPrevent.htm).

### Question/Doubt

We cannot eliminate Mutual Exclusion then **why is it one of the condition **??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We cannot Elimainate Mutual Exclusion then why is it one of the
>   condition ??

We cannot eliminate mutual exclusion in cases where we are dealing with **non-shareable resources**. So, it simply emphasizes that for special cases when we dealing with resources like `tap drive` and `printer`, which are **inherently non-shareable**, then we have to look at eliminating one of the other three options to prevent deadlock.

Now **Critical Section** does not always mean that we are talking about physical resources. It can also mean that we are talking about a `piece of code`. And `variables` are resources that are inherently **shareable resources**. So in such cases **we can eliminate mutual exclusion to prevent deadlock**. But keep in mind thats rarely done, because if we had ensured mutual exclusion in the initial design, it was there to ensure correct implementation. So just to make you aware that deadlock could be prevented by preventing mutual exclusion, but it does not mean that its practically prevalent.

Comment: @Summet : one more question ,we have to take risk of **inconsistent data** to ensure deadlock prevention .i mmean if we eliminate mutual exclusion  from **non inherently shareable resources**  then  it may be the case 2 process will be in critical section leading to incorrect data.!